# how to send message to particular user?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, ubuntu-18.04

I write a script that users with specific group do not enable to use cron in linux. how to when users login to system show this message that "Do Not Use Of Cron"?!
for example when user test login to bash (su -l test). message show that "Do Not Use Of Cron"

Comment: Currently your question is not clear. You should [edit] your question and write more details about what you want to achieve. Adding an example may help. Showing a message to the user when she logs in might depend on the shell the user chose as login shell. For graphical environments the approach will be different. In this case tell us which graphical desktop environment you use. Do you want to see the message after the graphical login or when the user opens a terminal window?

Answer (score 0):

To display a custom message to certain users when they log in via SSH, you can use a `Match` rule in your SSH configuration.

If all you want is display some helpful info for a specific user when he login, `Banner` directive can do this:

```
Match User <special_user>
    Banner /etc/ssh/banner.txt
```

With the above block in your SSH configuration, generally located, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, you can then put "Do Not Use Of Cron" in `/etc/ssh/banner.txt` for it to be displayed for that specific user

If you want the message to be displayed for more than one user, you can then add the same block again but amend the `<special_user>` with the username of that user.